# Php input verification

Tags: php

Is this how I would check if the input values have been filled out correctly? This isn't the beginning of this file.

```
<?php
if ($fname == "" || $lname == "" || $pass == "" || ($email == "" && $phone == ""))
{
    $error = "Not all fields were entered.<br />";
}
else
{ // Additional code
?>
```

Users can enter a phone or email, or both, but not neither.  Do I need to post more of my code? Thanks.

Comment: Test this code and check.

Comment: Why don't you just run the code and see it it works as expected? That would most likely have been faster than writing the question.

Comment: It looks correct, but you probably do not need to compare it to empty string. You could just treat them as booleans. `if (! $fname || ! $lname...`

Comment: How are those variables being populated in the first place? I would recommend a validation method before you get to the stage where you are trying to work with those variables. From a user experience standpoint it would be easier for the user to understand exactly which piece they did incorrectly rather than having a generic error message that says something wasn't entered

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct for your usecase! :)
I have a Suggestion for you - you could use a libary like GUMP (https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP) since it greatly simplifies input validation :)